# How can I use the HtmlHelper methods to create hyperlinks?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<div id="topmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Inicio</li>
        <li>Anuncios</li>
        <li>Registrate</li>
        <li>Ayuda</li>
        <li>Contacto</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I create links out of these elements? Html.Action()?

I don't see how to reference a controller and action AND set what the actual words to be displayed on the page.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You don't have a single hyperlink on the example - only list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Your text here", "ActionName", "ControllerName") %>
```

Comment: Since this question was tagged with mvc3, then I would recommend using the <%: %> tags instead.  For Html.ActionLink, it's not as big of a deal, but the : will automatically escape any HTML if the value doesn't implement IHtmlString.

Answer (score 1):

Try Html.ActionLink instead.

It creates a hyperlink and the first argument is the text to be displayed